# Azure AD B2C Implicit Grant is not working (how to disable authorization)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am using the following sample code from Microsoft to implement authentication for my web site (web application):

```
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-2-B2C
```

As described in the sample, I have created the Tenant, the "sign-up and sign-in user flow" and registered an application, that uses the flow, via the Azure portal.
But when I use the Integration Assistant (for the registered application), it reports that the following needs fixing:

```
If you are using the authorization code flow, disable the implicit grant settings.
-> Action required
```

According to the sample I MUST use implicit grant.
I do not need (my web site will not use) authorization, only authentication, and as far as I know, I have not selected "authorization code flow" anywhere.
Do anyone know what is wrong with the sample from Microsoft or idea of what can be done?

#### EDIT 2021-09-08

After doing some more research and receiving some advice here in the comments and in the suggested answer, I decided to find another example, instead of the out-of-date example above.

It looks like I should have asked for a better example, instead of how to fix the out-of-date example.

I hope this might be useful, for someone in the same situation as me.

**The best sample code I could find to get started was this one:**

JavaScript SPA secured with MSAL.js using the Authorization Code Flow (PKCE) on Azure AD B2C
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-b2c-javascript-spa

**And here is a description of the details regarding *authorization code flow*:**

OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow in Azure Active Directory B2C
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow

**And here is the startpage for how to use MSAL.js in a SPA for authentication and authorization with Azure B2C:**

Use the Microsoft Authentication Library for JavaScript to work with Azure AD B2C
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-b2c-overview

Comment: "Authorization code flow" is an authentication flow, just like implicit flow. The process for getting the user identity and access tokens is just different. A back-end ASP.NET Core app should use authorization code flow. Implicit flow is mainly for front-end JS apps. I disagree with what they say in the sample :)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Microsoft's AADB2C code samples uses implicit grant and elsewhere they say not to use implicit grant, but does not mention what to use instead, nor how to modify the implicit grant examples. Do you know if some up to date examples exist for AADB2C with SPA + Web API + Federated Authentication?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Juunas for your comment. I agree with ("Authorization code flow" is an authentication flow, just like implicit flow. The process for getting the user identity and access tokens is just different)

To register a single-page application (SPA) in the Microsoft identity platform : The registration steps differ between MSAL.js 1.0, which supports the implicit grant flow, and MSAL.js 2.0, which supports the authorization code flow with PKCE.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-app-registration#redirect-uri-msaljs-10-with-implicit-flow

Comment: Does the link to the documentation for active-directory work for the b2c scenario I mentioned or are there some subtle differences?

Comment: MSAL for JavaScript enables client-side JavaScript web applications, running in a web browser, to authenticate users using Azure AD work and school accounts (AAD), Microsoft personal accounts (MSA) and social identity providers like Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, Microsoft accounts, etc. through Azure AD B2C service. It also enables your app to get tokens to access Microsoft Cloud services such as Microsoft Graph.

Comment: I know all you write, but it does not explain how to modify the sample provided by Microsoft. Guess I will have to start from scratch and read MSAL and OIDC docs. I had the impression that authentication would be handled for me, by azure, but seems I was rong.